# C# to Android chat client

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, xamarin

I have created a LAN chat messaging application using C# that connects all clients who run the program to a server on my computer.

I am now trying to convert this application to work with android devices via Xamarin Studio.

When testing this, the device correctly connects to the server as it can send a message ( saying the device has logged in) which is then broadcasted to the other clients.

However, once the application sends this message the program then closes immediately.

Within the desktop version of the chat client I use the code(which is ran on another thread):

```
NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
private void getMessage()
    {
        while (this.keepOpen)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("getMessage");
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Read stream");
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                Console.WriteLine ("Final test");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed to read stream");
            }


            string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + returndata;
            message();
        }
    }
```

This works the first time it is called as the line "Final test" is displayed. However, after this, when the method gets to this stage again (as it is in a never ending loop) I get an error message saying:

'[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 13.455MB for 4194308-byte allocation'

'[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 21.444MB for 8388612-byte allocation'

And the line "Final test" is not shown thus the line 'serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);' is crashing the app. I have tried to use .Flush() and .Close() however none of these work.

The sending portion of my code runs perfectly using 'serverSocket.Write()' as other clients can receive the messages so why would reading data from the server crash the app?

P.S This is my first android app so I wanted to use a language I was more comfortable with than attempting from scratch with java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised that this error was because I was allocating too much memory when trying to send a messag.

Simple changed

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
```

To

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[4096];
buffSize = 4096;
```